# Silverlight WCF hosting

Tags: asp.net, wcf, silverlight

I have a silverlight application with WCF. I have deployed this application for testing on server, the application is accessed using public IP. On the same server I also hosted WCF services which are used by silverlight application. These services also can be accessed using same public IP but with different port.
In XAP file I updated the service reference URLs (with public IP) and application worked just fine. 
Later on I thought instead of using public IP for these services in application reference I should just use **localhost** because silverlight application and services both are on same IIS and it would improve response time of application.

Old Urls in ServiceReference file

```
http://public_ip:8080/servicename.svc
```

New Urls ServiceReference file

```
http://localhost:8080/servicename.svc
```

But after doing this my application didn't work.
Can anyone help me understanding why I can't use localhost as service reference?

Comment: I think this is likely a common misconception for those coming from ASP.NET development into Silverlight. Code from within ASP.NET pages is all executed on the server, and only markup is sent to the client. For Silverlight, however, the XAP file is hosted up to the client, and actually is executed by the client itself. Thus, all the code is from the context of the client.

Comment: @MikeGuthrie thanks! very well explained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XAP file contains code which is run on the client machine. In this context LocalHost would refer to the machine that is hosting the browser session, not the server hosting the website. From the client machine you need the fully qualified URL to find the service.